# How to convert GeoTIFF to png?

Tags: python, geotiff

How to convert GeoTIFF to png, the following code does it wrong because after converting I get a blank background (something like a layer in GIMP). And I try to open in tkinter to I get an error. I know I may be confusing some information but I only need a png as a thumbnail for the gallery. Thank you for your help.

P.S. I know, the code is not easy but it's a quickly made draft/test version.

```py
import rasterio
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()
west, south, east, north = 0, 0, 0, 0

dataset = rasterio.open('link to GeoTIFF', 'r')
bands = [1, 2, 3]
data = dataset.read(bands)
transform = rasterio.transform.from_bounds(west, south, east, north, data.shape[1], data.shape[2])
crs = {'init': 'epsg:3006'}

with rasterio.open('link to save png', 'w', driver='GTiff',
                   width=data.shape[1], height=data.shape[2],
                   count=3, dtype=data.dtype, nodata=0,
                   transform=transform, crs=crs) as dst:
    dst.write(data, indexes=bands)

load = Image.open('link to open png in tkinter')
render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
img = tk.Label(root, image=render)
img.image = render

root.mainloop()
```

Error:

```
raise UnidentifiedImageError(
    PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file 'link to file *.*png'
```

[image: Result of GeoTIFF to png conversion]

Answer (score 0):

Image.open is not able to identify the image file. Check the file size before opening the file. `os.path.getsize(fname_image)`

This should be greater than 0. Next add arguments to identify the image

```
with rasterio.open('link to save png', 'w', driver='PNG',
               width=data.shape[1], height=data.shape[2],
               count=3, dtype=data.dtype, nodata=0,
               transform=transform, crs=crs, format='PNG') as dst:
```

dst.write(data, indexes=bands)

```
load = Image.open('link to open png in tkinter').convert("RGB")
```

Comment: Hello,
thank you for your help. From the file I got the value 54572213 then I need to convert it now to north, south... that is height, width (this is the first time I use this transformation tool) and I got the error 'PNG driver doesn't support data type Float32. Only eight bit (Byte) and sixteen bit (UInt16) bands supported. '. Could you still help me with this. Thank you very much :)

Comment: convert the data to unsigned 8/16 integer and then save for png. you can use numpy library for this

Comment: Thank you for the tip, with just more to ask because I don't understand what this is (what to put here?) `west, south, east, north`. Thank you very much :D

Comment: 0, 0, 0, 0, - a bit on intuition I typed ;)